# How can you use php xdebug if you are on NAT behind a firewall?

Tags: php, firewall, xdebug, remote-debugging

I have the following use case for debugging a PHP application:

- The developer does have a private IP address
- The developer can connect only to a limited number of ports from the server, like 80, 8080, 3128, others being limited by the outgoing firewall. Still if the outgoing requests are HTTP he could use a proxy that does not have this limitation.
- the server machine is fully configurable

Is is possible to use xdebug in this circumstance? How?

It is possible to establish a VPN but this is not an easy solution so I would prefer a simplified one.

Comment: Have you read this : http://derickrethans.nl/debugging-with-multiple-users.html ? It might interest you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution I found was to use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to forward the port `9000` from the server to the client (IDE).

[image: putty configuration screenshot]

Just configure the Xdebug to connect to the `localhost` instead of an IP address your client (IDE) is running on:

```
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
```

There is [a nice article called *Remote Debugging PHP with a Firewall in the Way*](https://derickrethans.nl/debugging-with-xdebug-and-firewalls.html) describing this and also the Xdebug configuration and SSH port forwarding method.

Answer (score 5):

Another variant is to use SSH port forwarding (can be used also in [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com)).

Simply execute:

```
ssh -R 9000:127.0.0.1:9000 host.example.com
```

It creates a tunnel which forwards the port `9000` on the remote host to the port `9000` on the localhost.

Everything else is the same as in the PuTTY method (see *sorin*'s answer).

Comment: parameter should be -R

Comment: You save my dayssssssss!!!!! I've been search a lots places, finally you saved me!!!!!!