# Remote PHP Debugging with Netbeans and XDebug (remote server)

Tags: xdebug

I've seen all other topics on this subject and incorporated all recommendations, but still it doesn't work.
I'm trying to debug my NetBeans project using xDebug that I've installed on remote server. I have all required settings configured properly but still can't get xDebug to stop at a breakpoint (information from phpinfo()):

```
xdebug.remote_enable    On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  62.216.43.2
xdebug.remote_port  9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back On
The ports are equal both on remote server and in Netbeans - 9000.
```

I've checked "break at first line" flag and made sure that xdebug.idekey is netbeans-xdebug in phpinfo(). After I run debugger it opens the following:
after run the debugger will open this url
http://my.ip.address.here/inreado.com/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
The project is set up to run as http://my.ip.address.here/inreado.com.

I presume that the problem could be with remote_host setting or project URL:
My IP address inside local area network is 192.168.0.188, where and my external IP is 62.216.43.2. Either of them as remote_host value yields no result.
Or maybe the problem is with the URL as it's not proper DNS name.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: The problem is with the NAT mechanism. [Here is][1] the possible solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794027/how-can-you-use-php-xdebug-if-you-are-on-nat-behind-a-firewall

Answer (score 1):

Remember you need to set the Path Mapping in the Debugger tab inside Netbeans Options.

Another little big problem I was having when trying to connect from NetBeans remotely was the SSH tunnel. You have to creat it for the port xdebug will work on, 9000 usually.

If you experience network problems for a moment, the tunnel might "break" silently and NetBeans will be stuck in the holy "Waiting for connection..." state. In putty, you can right click and Restart Session, but this won't work.

You will need to close the putty window and re open the session for it to work again.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually, closing the putty window doesn't do the trick. What you might need is to recreate the tunnel. To do so, there is a command you can install called "cutter" that will let you kill the tunnel, I haven't tried it yet but it's worth a try. I'll comment on it later.