# Remote debugging server 2008, PHP, IIS, Xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug, windows-server-2008-r2, netbeans-8

I am using NetBeans to remotely debug my code on server 2008 R2 running IIS 7, PHP 7 with Xdebug version 2.6.1. Debugging on my personal computer works fine but remote debugging on server gets stuck forever on "waiting for connection". When I check server for Xdebug log I see this:

```
Log opened at 2018-10-17 12:48:22
I: Connecting to configured address/port: MYIPADDR:9001.
E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(
Log closed at 2018-10-17 12:48:22
```

Can some one help me get this working? Thank you in advance.

Searching on internet shows SSH as a solution but I cannot install SSH server there.

Comment: 1) Ensure that Server can make outgoing connections on that `9001` port; 2) Ensure that you can accept incoming connections on your computer on that port. It could be a firewall or most likely a router (you need to allow/do port forwarding there). That's why SSH is a good way .. as in this case you are connecting to the server (and then Xdebug works through the tunnel) and not other way around. So far it most likely a router issue + possibly wrong IP address.

Comment: @LazyOne thank you for your input. Unfortunately I cannot do any modification to server firewall or routers. I am just a developer, I wonder how other php developers are getting around this problem.

Comment: for those having similar issues have a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794027/how-can-you-use-php-xdebug-if-you-are-on-nat-behind-a-firewall